# Click Outside the RecyclerView to Hide ChildView in RecyclerView Row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple `RecyclerView` and when you `LongClick` a Row in `RecyclerView` I make a hidden `LinearLayout` visible on that row. To do so In my `public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` I am using the following

```
LinearLayout REACTION_LAYOUT = RecyclerItem.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.reaction_layout);
RecyclerItem.LongClick += (sender, e) => { OnLongClick(REACTION_LAYOUT); };
```

`REACTION_LAYOUT` is the layout I am showing using the following

```
private void OnLongClick(LinearLayout _ReactionLayout)
        {
            try
            {  
                _ReactionLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            }
            catch (Exception X)
            {
                Log.Info("1022585", "CLICK (ERROR) : " + X.Message);
            }
        }
```

This works as Intended, Now what I want is to HIDE the `REACTION_LAYOUT` when a user touches anywhere outside the Row which means on other rows in RecyclerView or anywhere else

How do I do that?

The approach I tried to use was to detect a touch on `parent` within my Adapter's `OnCreateViewHolder` as following

```
parent.Click += (sender, e) => { OnParentClick(REACTION_LAYOUT); };
```

This works but It disables the scrolling on recycler view.

What is the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT**: The activity RecyclerView is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_message_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
  <include layout="@layout/toolbar_messages"/>   
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="4.5dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
      android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>  
  <RelativeLayout     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">   
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/rvMessages"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"      
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"/>  .......
```

**EDIT 2:**

Also tried to set the OnTouchLisener, but still no luck

```
public class _OnRecylerTouch_Listener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnTouchListener
        {
            private LinearLayout _L;
            public _OnRecylerTouch_Listener(LinearLayout L)
            {
                _L = L;
            }
            public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
            {
                _L.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you add your code into Recylerview itemView.onClick method

Comment: What is the parent layout of the recyclerview?

Comment: @Ali Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above it's very wired code btw. From what I get, if your solution was working fine, but nested scroll doesn't  in this case.

```
public class _OnRecylerTouch_Listener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnTouchListener
        {
            private LinearLayout _L;
            public _OnRecylerTouch_Listener(LinearLayout L)
            {
                _L = L;
            }
            public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
            {
                 if (_L.Visibility == ViewStates.VISIBLE) {
                    _L.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                     return true;
                 }
                 return false;
            }
        }
```

And next change your `onLongClickListener` to the next.

```
private void OnLongClick(LinearLayout _ReactionLayout)
    {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
            public void run() 
            {
               try {  
                    _ReactionLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                 }

                catch (Exception X)
                {
                    Log.Info("1022585", "CLICK (ERROR) : " + X.Message);
                }

            }, 100);

        }
    }
```

And you issue should be resolved.

EXPLANATION

All you need it's do not intercept touch event. Which should be consumed by inner scroll. And action for `onLongClickListener` should fire visibility changes after `onTouch` to work properly. *It's not a best solution, but here is your problem, so you can figure out the reason.*

Comment: Yep, I tried that also, Also I tried with `if(e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)` THEN true otherwise false but still no luck

Comment: @Ali Motion event should nothing do here. Plug exactly what the above.

Comment: Plugged exactly above, scrolling is working now but `_L` is not hiding on `ViewStates.Gone`

Comment: @Ali Seems I found the problem. Pls check the above methods. Plug exactly the same, and this work for you.

Comment: Thanks, mate, yes I need to find a better solution for the issue, Thanks for your help, marking it right answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

THis method call whenever you click on recylerview item

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
               // Add your functionalities here

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

check if this helps you with disabled scrolling:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: No luck with this also